# How to make a 3D model viewer android app?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to make my own 3d viewer app.

I just want it works like,

1. Open an app (tap on my smartphone screen),
2. Show a 3d model,
3. Close the app when the back button is tapped.

Actually, I made an app (with Kotlin on android studio) that is working like my idea.

The app is working well with a file that is located on a server.
But I want to make an app that works without an internet connection.

**How to import a file(glTF format) to the app.?**

In the part,

.appendQueryParameter("file", "**PATH**/XXXX.gltf")

If the **PATH** is with "https//", it works with an internet connection.

but, How can I set the **PATH** local storage in order for the apps to work without internet connections?

Here is the kotlin code snippet that I'm using.

```
        val sceneViewerIntent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val intentUri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0").buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(
                "file","ludovic_v2_gltf.gltf" //<<<<---- how to import this file?
                //"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf" 
                //<<<--- with this line, works very well.
            )
            .appendQueryParameter("mode", "3d_only")
            .build()
        sceneViewerIntent.data = intentUri
        sceneViewerIntent.setPackage("com.google.ar.core")
        startActivity(sceneViewerIntent)
        finish()
```

Thanks a lot!!!

This is my environment.

windows10, android-studio 20212.1Patch1(build on May 18,2022)

My project was started with "empty activity".

Comment: Did you search for "glTF format"?

Comment: @cliff2310 yes, I did. but I could not find any similar cases.